# How to update the mesh state after modifying the mesh's rotation mode?

Tags: scripting

I need to set the matrix_world of the mesh in quaternion rotation mode. However, the position and size of the object will be abnormal after modifying the parameters in the undo menu.

bpy.context.view_layer.update() can solve the problem:

```py
rotation_mode = ""
if obj.rotation_mode != 'QUATERNION':
    rotation_mode = obj.rotation_mode
    obj.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
obj.matrix_world = M @ obj.matrix_world
if rotation_mode != "":
    obj.rotation_mode = rotation_mode
```

Is this the correct approach?
Thanks

Comment: From your script, I see that `rotation_mode` remains the same as the original. the object `matrix_world` can set directly without change the `rotation_mode`, so just remove all lines except line 6

Comment: @XY After restarting the computer, I can't reproduce the bug, I don't understand it.